# How do I resolve the Spatial types and functions are not available ... Microsoft.SqlServer.Types for a console app?

Tags: c#, sql-server, geospatial, nuget-package

I'm working on a console app to load some data from a CSV into a local SQL Server 2016 database. I first ran into an error that said the spatial types were not available for assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Types version 10 and above. Searching here on SO I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174197/microsoft-sqlserver-types-version-10-or-higher-could-not-be-found-on-azure) that seemed to address this, although it was for Azure. Still I installed the NuGet package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, but that didn't help. Searching more I came across this blog post [Solving the “Spatial types and functions are not available …” -problem](https://www.koskila.net/2016/06/07/solving-the-spatial-types-and-functions-are-not-available-problem/). I issued the Update-Package command, but that resulted in an error in the package manager console that says:

```
[Failure] Could not find file 'D:\ScratchSrc\ReadCDC\ReadCDC\SqlServerTypes\Loader.cs
```

How do I resolve this?