# What does Microsoft.SqlServer.Types do, and how does it work?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nuget-package

I am being told to use `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` for `DbGeography` in a homework project I have. The homework project is with ASP.NET, and is trying to use a database to do a search on stuff in the db. (The database is supposed to be from a `.bak` file, but I had to upload a `.bacpac` file into azure and then connect back to it, since the `.bak` file keeps saying it's corrupt).

This is a code block that I have been told to put into the `Global.asax.cs` file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // For Spatial types, i.e. DbGeography
    SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
    // This next line is a fix that came from:       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174197/microsoft-sqlserver-types-version-10-or-higher-could-not-be-found-on-azure/40166192#40166192
    SqlProviderServices.SqlServerTypesAssemblyName = typeof (SqlGeography).Assembly.FullName;

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

I have looked at the [documentation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/), and the darned thing just says:

> ## Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
>
> Allows you to use SQL Server spatial types on a machine without SQL Server installed. Enables Entity Framework spatial types to be used (DbGeography and DbGeometry).

Which *I think* just means that this package enables us to use c expression for SQL, but I would like a better explanation. I have no clue what `DbGeography` and `DbGeometry` do.

Additionally, I would like to know if this is applicable to an azure-based db, and not just a local db made from a .bak file.

Answer (score 10):

> I have no clue what DbGeography and DbGeometry do.

It's simple. SQL Server has [spatial types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/spatial-types-geometry-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  .NET does not.

`Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` is a library you can add to your .NET project to work with SQL Server `geography` and `geometry` data types in your .NET project.  Without this library you can only read and write SQL Server spatial types by converting them to text in the [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) format.

For most of the other data types supported by SQL Server there's a corresponding .NET type that works.  Eg SQL Server has `int` .NET has `System.Int32`, etc.

Comment: Adding that spatial types can be used in the on-prem SQL Server editions and Azure.

Comment: Also required for returning hierarchyid type which I just discovered in case that helps anyone