# DbGeography does not work when published to a server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, dbgeography

The following code works in my local machine while debugging but throws an error when published to a server.

```
public IEnumerable<Restaurant> Nearby(double latitude, double longitude, double distance)
{
    var region = DbGeography.PointFromText(string.Format("POINT({1} {0})", latitude, longitude), 4326).Buffer(10000);
    return Find(x => SqlSpatialFunctions.Filter(x.Location, region) ?? false);
}
```

After searching like a madman, I installed Microsoft.SqlServer.Types from nuget. (version 14.0.1016.290)

Added the required dlls in the ~/bin folder (provided by the above package).

Added the following code in  Global.asax.cs

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(Server.MapPath("~/bin"));
```

But still the code throws a "500 Internal Server Error. An error has occured".

Note: This works perfectly in my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whew, finally this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40166192/13157849) worked.

Note: I had to include **Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll** from

*~/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.14.0.1016.290\lib\net40* in the ~/bin folder as well